# Random vertex colors for uv islands

Tags: uv, vertex-colors

Is it possible to auto assign random vertex colors for every UV island... so it will be more visible in the 3d view?
Like in 3d-coat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a new Cycles only feature, but yes. In material nodes, try using Geometry>Random Per Island. Map and control the output via color ramps. [image]

Comment: I think this might not actually be UV islands but mesh islands.

Comment: Oh snap, you're right. Now that geo nodes and more have been updated, it should be possible to have actual UV islands with random colors. I'll have to look into it.